# How to use ExpandableObjectConverter on property of abstract type in PropertyInspector

Tags: c#, wpf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4

I want to have the `PropertyInspector` allow me to select the concrete type of the instance to set in a property of an abstract type and expand into the properties of that type using the [+] sign as is normally provided by the `ExpandableObjectConverter`.

However it seems that when using an abstract type as the property, the only selectable value in the list is `(null)`, and nothing gets expanded. This I can understand since there is no way for the editor to know which types I want to provide.

But if I provide by own editor using the EditorAttribute that assigns to the property a concrete instance derived from the abstract type, no [+]-sign appears and I cannot expand into the sub-properties.

I was using some simple test classes like the following:

```
public abstract class Test
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestImpl : Test
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MyObject
{
   [TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
   public Test MyTest { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve what I want, i.e. to have the MyTest property have an editor allowing me to select the concrete type I want, and when I have done so, a [+] sign should appear to allow me to set the properties of that object?

**Edit:**

When using a normal PropertyGrid in Windows Forms the following converter would do pretty much exactly what I want:

```
public class MyConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
   public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
   {
      return true;
   }

   public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
   {
      StandardValuesCollection coll = new StandardValuesCollection(new Test[] {  new TestImpl() });
      return coll;
   }

   public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
   {
      return sourceType == typeof(string);
   }

   public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
   {
      return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType((string)value));
   }
}
```

However in the workflow designer (or PropertyInspector) it seems to add no functionality at all (or at least not the one I want).  In fact it seems that no methods on the converter are even called, which seems very strange.

Changing the type of the property `MyObject.MyTest` to `TestImpl`, the `ExpandableObjectConverter` does work.

(In reality of course there would be more than one class deriving from the abstract `Test`)

Comment: I was under the impression that the PropertyInspector stuff was all related to, and provided by the Workflow designer and related assemblies, i.e. via WF4. If I'm mistaken here, and it is available in standard WPF as well please feel free to retag the post or let me know so I can fix it.

Comment: Could have *sworn* it was more generalized, but I can't find any evidence of this.  My bad.  I stink.  +1 for learning something new.